# c++ templates: Can/how do I use a struct as the instantiated type for a template?

Tags: c++, templates

Specifics:

I'd like to have the following struct

```
struct edgeT {      
  string home;      
  string away;      
  int weight;  
};
```

And then have a priority queue of type edgeT.

I wrote a quick program to test the priority queue, but I'm getting the following error msg.

> 'Template argument for 'template class minPQ' uses local type 'Main()::edgeT'

I just defined/declared the struct at the start of the main() routine.

Does the struct have to be defined somewhere else?

Comment: Can you show us how you're attempting to use `minPQ` and what line the error is on?

Comment: You are missing a strict weak ordering comparator for `edgeT`, but the error you quote points to another error.

Comment: Move the definition of `edgeT` outside of `main` (it also looks like you may have named it incorrectly as `Main`, C++ is case-sensitive). Alternately, if you're using gcc, try compiling with the `-std=c++11` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Only since C++11 you can use types defined in functions as template arguments. Either use C+11, or put your struct definition at namespace scope.